# nvidia 525 disabling using ironhide

Tags: 11.10, intel-graphics, nvidia-optimus, xps, hybrid-graphics

I have installed ironhide using ppa [11.10 - 32 bit, Dell xps 15]. After rebooting I tried to disable nvidia gpu using the command "sudo ironhide-disablecard". I got message as "ERROR : no module for nvidia found at /proc/modules" and "nvidia card disabled successfully". Is it a normal behavior? Please note I tried disabling the card without trying to enable it.

```
Thank You
```

Comment: I would try installing Bumblebee 3.0. A bit of info here:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work/36936#36936

Comment: Did you try a recent version of Ubuntu and Bumblebee?

Answer (score 1):

Currently ironhide is no longer maintained.
You should install Bumblebee instead using the `bumblebee/stable` ppa.

But to answer your question:
"Disabling" the nvidia card in this way does nothing. By default the nvidia card is not used, only when using `optirun <command>`. The nvidia card cannot be disabled any more then to deprive it of it's drivers and run on intel only.

However there is a possible workaround I read, which is to reverse engineer the windows drivers to find the ACPI calls needed, then create a script for it yourself. Not recommended unless you are an expert on this.

Comment: As a Bumblebee developer, I can tell you for sure that we're *not* reverse engineering the Windows drivers. After analysis of a lot ACPI tables, I crafted a new module for toggling the power. Expect the new release within two weeks.

Comment: That's another way to find them. Didn't mean to suggest you were doing so. Great to hear this development. I look forward to it!

Comment: FYI, Bumblebee 3.0 has been released a few days ago and detects the right method automatically. There is no need for customizing ACPI calls anymore. http://askubuntu.com/a/36936/6969

Comment: Ty, running it with great enjoyment of my added battery time and greater resolutions on my MiniDP.